# Exporting file status list from TortoiseHg workbench Commit view?

Tags: tortoisehg

Summary:
Does anyone know how to export the contents of the commit view of the TortoiseHg workbench to a text file?

Context:
When I do a complex merge, I usually keep a merge log while working, and I would like to the contents of the commit view in the workbench as a text file.
So: first column with "Stat", second column with "M", third column with "Filename".

What I tried:
I tried selecting all lines in the view and copy + paste in a text file, but that doesn't work.

So: how can I copy that file list (including status and merge status prefix) to a text file?
Or is there a Mercurial command that I can execute on the command line that shows the same (file + status + merge status)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could open the terminal (menu Repository->Terminal, shorcut  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
hg status
```

Comment: In the meantime, I had found that I needed to combine these two commands: for a list of modified files: hg status, and for a list of unresolved conflicts: hg resolve -l